List all tasks in ClickUp with custom field named NIRV (checkbox) is checked
How can I list all tasks where a custom field (Checkbox) named "NIRV" is checked?
Here is my code.
import requests

# Constants
API_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
FOLDER_ID = '544444444444444444444'

# Function to get lists inside a folder
def get_lists_in_folder(folder_id):
url = f"https://api.clickup.com/api/v2/folder/{folder_id}/list"
headers = {
    "Authorization": API_KEY
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response.raise_for_status()
return response.json()["lists"]

# Function to get tasks from a list
 def get_clickup_tasks(list_id):
url = f"https://api.clickup.com/api/v2/list/{list_id}/task"
headers = {
    "Authorization": API_KEY
}
params = {
    "subtasks": "true",
    "include_closed": "false"  # Exclude closed tasks
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
response.raise_for_status()
return response.json()["tasks"]

 # Function to filter tasks with 'NIRV' checkbox checked
 def filter_nirvana_tasks(tasks):
nirvana_tasks = []
for task in tasks:
    custom_fields = task.get("custom_fields", [])
    for custom_field in custom_fields:
        if custom_field["name"] == "Nirv" and custom_field.get("value") == True:
            nirvana_tasks.append(task)
            break  # Move to the next task once we find the Nirv field checked
return nirvana_tasks

# Main script
 lists = get_lists_in_folder(FOLDER_ID)

 for lst in lists:
list_id = lst['id']
tasks = get_clickup_tasks(list_id)
nirvana_tasks = filter_nirvana_tasks(tasks)

if nirvana_tasks:
    print(f"Tasks in List ID {list_id} with 'NIRV' checked:")
    for task in nirvana_tasks:
        print(f"Task ID: {task['id']}")
else:
    print(f"No tasks in List ID {list_id} with 'NIRV' checked.")

The output of this code is shwon below. I am sure that list 900201998483 has custom field checked.
No tasks in List ID 900201998483 with 'NIRV' checked.
No tasks in List ID 900201249353 with 'NIRV' checked.
No tasks in List ID 900201249363 with 'NIRV' checked.
No tasks in List ID 900201249293 with 'NIRV' checked.
No tasks in List ID 900700176764 with 'NIRV' checked.
.
.
.

I figured it out. I have to enclose the word True in quotation marks
if custom_field["name"] == "Nirv" and custom_field.get("value") == "True":
nirvana_tasks.append(task)

Another way is to include the filter in your request parameters:
parameters = {
    "subtasks": "true",
    "include_closed": "false",
    'custom_fields': json.dumps([
    {
        'field_id': 'PASTE_FIELD_ID_HERE',
        'operator': '=',
        'value': 'NIRV'
        }
    ])
}

